# Array Index out of bounds although enough space available

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing a piece of Java code that reads in data from a .txt file and stores it in a 2D array. For some files, the code works perfectly fine, but for other files, it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, even though as far as I can tell, the array has enough space!

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExtractData {
    static String[][] data;
    static String line;
    static int amountOfEntries;
    static int amountOfSeparators;

    public static String[][] getData(String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        System.out.println("Fetching data for file " + filename);
        amountOfEntries = Utilities.countLines(filename);
        amountOfSeparators = (Utilities.countOccurencesOfCharacter(filename, ' ') / amountOfEntries) + 1;

        String[] temp = new String[amountOfEntries]; // for extracted data, still needs to be separated 
        int alpha = 0;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            temp[alpha] = line;
            alpha++;
        }   
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Done!");

        System.out.println("Parsing Data to Cache...");
        String[][] parsedData = new String[amountOfEntries][amountOfSeparators];

        String[] parts = new String[amountOfSeparators];
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfEntries; i++) {
            parts = (temp[i]).split("   "); 
            for (int k = 0; k < amountOfSeparators; k++) {
                parsedData[i][k] = parts[k];
                Utilities.debugMethod(filename + "[" + i + "][" + k + "]", parsedData[i][k]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
        return parsedData;
    }

    public static void fetchDataAndParsetoSQL(String filename) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Present working directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        data = getData(filename);
        System.out.println("Creating SQL statements and writing to file...");
        String tablename = Utilities.sqltableName(filename);
        toSQL.SQLOutput(data, tablename, filename);
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

I get the Exception on the  line

```
    parsedData[i][k] = parts[k];
```

This is extremely annoying, and I can't seem to find an answer to the problem anywhere, especially since even with the text files it doesn't work on, it still parses the first 60 lines of the file correctly before throwing the exception.

Anyone have an idea what could cause this?

Comment: Please show the exact exception, along with the values of `i` and `k`. Note that the code you've presented wouldn't even compile, as `'  '` isn't a valid character literal.

Comment: shouldn't the loop condition take the parts[] length into account?

Comment: The exception tells you the size of the array and the index value being used.  One of those is not what you expect.  And *always* quote the *entire* and *exact* error message when complaining about an error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parts = (temp[i]).split("   ");
```

This line returns a *new* array, which is then stored in variable `parts`. The array you originally created is no longer referred to by `parts`.

This new array, created by `split()`, will contain as many elements as there were elements between the separators. It is not guaranteed to have exactly `amountOfSeparators` elements or more. Your inner loop declaration needs to be:

```
for(int k = 0; k < amountOfSeparators && k < parts.size(); k++) {
```

(Also a note on style: use consistent spaces around operators, e.g. `k < amountOfSeparators` not `k< amountOfSeparators`, and use more descriptive iterators than `i`, `k`, as in this case they do have a meaning other than naïve iterators and you have  a number of them—better names can make it a lot easier to follow complex loops.)

Comment: Thank you this fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that the `parts` array will always have `amountOfSeparators` elements, but each time you assign to it a new array by calling `parts = (temp[i]).split("   ");`, and some of those calls probably return a shorter array than you expect.

The following code will make sure that the `parts` array has the required length:

```
parts = (temp[i]).split(" ");
parts = Arrays.copyOf(parts, amountOfSeparators);
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what happens, just printed out le length of parts for every recursive call. However, when     (temp[i]).split("   ");     has f.i. 74 entries, and parts 77, how can I set the remaining, unused indexes to let's say null? I thought this would be automatically ...

Comment: @SpadeJohnsson You can create a new array of `amountOfSeparators` elements in each iteration and then copy to it the elements of the `(temp[i]).split(" ")` array. This way the unused indices will be null.

Comment: @SpadeJohnsson Or better - `parts = (temp[i]).split("   "); parts = Arrays.copyOf(parts,amountOfSeparators);`